# Ice formation in a cavity that was sealed at ambient condition and taken to space

Tags: space, ice

I have a hardware with a cavity that was closed (welded) at ambient conditions (298K, 1 bar Pressure and 50% RH). The hardware was taken to space where the temperature can go down to near zero Kelvin. Will there be any ice formation? And will it be a hard ice or more like a snow?

I can imagine ice formation but I suspect it will not be like an ice crystal but more like snow. Can somebody explain this? Thank you.

Comment: I would be concerned about your hardware being able to withstand the 14.7 psi of outward pressure from the air inside the cavity, as there's no atmospheric pressure in space to push back against it.

Comment: @probably_someone And any additional pressure that could be brought on if exposed to the sun would make it worse.

Comment: @JMac Exactly. It's hard to get rid of heat in space, as you can't exactly conduct or convect it away, and the Sun is just as strong of a heat source as it is on the ground.

Comment: @probably_someone pressure is not the problem, the walls are thick enough for that. In fact, I am talking about a hardware that could withstand much higher pressure difference across the wall. My concern is a diaphragm inside the hardware which is effectively facing no pressure difference across it but if hard ice forms on one side, it might damage it. And regarding dissipating heat, what about radiation?

Comment: @ManishKumarMishra It's not the thickness of the walls that matters, but rather the integrity of the weld/sealant. And of course there is radiation, but at low (i.e. not-visibly-glowing) temperatures, it doesn't transfer all that much heat away. Anyway, let's compare the two situations: on the ground, you can get rid of the Sun's heat through conduction, convection, _and_ radiation. In space, you can only get rid of the Sun's heat by radiation. Therefore, you're going to heat up more from the Sun in space than you would in-atmosphere.

Comment: @probably_someone You are right about the integrity of the weld, but let's assume we have proof-tested the hardware and it is alright at ambient and low-temperature conditions. Radiation on earth will be negligible due to the small difference in temperature of hardware and surrounding while it will be much larger in space. Anyways, I do think you are right, the hardware will heat up more in space in presence of the sun. But what about the eclipse phase? Will there be ice formation inside the cavity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambient temperature may be near $0K$, but the temperature of the device will not be that low, as it is still going to absorb heat from the sun (assuming it is still in the solar system), in fact, it will actually be very hot, rather than being cold.

The heat list through radiation is lower (at low temperatures) than the heat gained. The heat gain and loss will come to an equilibrium at a higher temperature than the freezing point of water

The heat loss by radiation depends on temperature, and is given by the formula:
$$\frac{Q}{t}=\sigma{e}AT^{4}$$

Where $\sigma$ is the Stephan-Boltzman constant. And, $ e $ is the emissivity of the object.

At equilibrium,

$$ Q _{absorbed} = Q _{radiated} $$

So,

$$ {1366.1} \times {e} \times A = 5.67 \times 10^{-8} \times e \times A \times T^4 $$

Solving for T (Area and e get canceled on both sides), we get,

$$ T = 393.98 K $$

Also, I suggest you read the article [here](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/14-7-radiation/).

Comment: Hi, I am not very sure if that is true. The component will be losing heat by radiation to the environment and heat influx from sun will be very low given the small cross-section to receive it. I am guessing you might have missed the radiation mode of losing heat. Please let me know if there is something I misunderstood.

Comment: At normal room temperature, the rate of losing heat by radiation will be a lot lower than the rate of absorbing heat. At higher temperatures, the rate of absorbing will be lower than rate of losing heat. It will come to an equilibrium at some temperature between these. Hence, it will be in equilibrium at a high temperature.

Comment: I have added some extra information about radiation in my answer.

Comment: Hi, as I said in the previous comment, I am not convinced that heat absorbed is as high as you are assuming it to be. For example, assuming the object is at a distance from the sun as earth & has a cross-section width of 1 m^2 (which is quite high) - the energy input will be ~ 1400 W. Now, if we calculate the temperature of body assuming some vacuum temperature to balance the energy input & output, it will come very close the vacuum temperature. So, the temperature will fall well below the freezing point unless there is some heat generation within. [please correct me if I am wrong]

Comment: @ManishKumarMishra, I have added the working of the solution to get the final value in the answer. Hope it clarifies your doubt.